# React Bootstrap Tabs Component's transition prop not working

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

When `transition` prop of React bootstrap Tabs is set to`false` it works. But when set to true as the example below it throws following exception.

```
<Tabs transition>
    <Tab title='Component 1'><Component1/></Tab>
    <Tab title='Component 2'><Component2/></Tab>
</Tabs>
```

```
index.js:1437 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: boolean.

Check the render method of `TabPane`.
    in TabPane (created by Tabs)
    in div (created by TabContent)
    in TabContent (created by Bootstrap(TabContent))
    in Bootstrap(TabContent) (created by Tabs)
    in TabContainer (created by Tabs)
    in Tabs (created by Uncontrolled(Tabs))
    in Uncontrolled(Tabs) (created by ForwardRef)
    in ForwardRef (at CTabs.js:67)
    in CTabs (created by Context.Consumer)
    in withRouter(CTabs) (at App.js:73)
    in Router (created by HashRouter)
    in HashRouter (at App.js:71)
    in header (at App.js:47)
    in div (at App.js:46)
```

What am i not getting?

Comment: what's version of  `react-bootstrap` ?

Comment: "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.10",

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe this is a bug.

From source code of [`TabContainer.js`](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/src/TabContainer.js#L42), the comment said it allowed true / false, but actually it only accepts `false` and `PropTypes.elementType`.

This is the reason of the error.

```
 /**
     * Sets a default animation strategy for all children `<TabPane>`s. Use
     * `false` to disable, `true` to enable the default `<Fade>` animation or
     * a react-transition-group v2 `<Transition/>` component.
     *
     * @type {{Transition | false}}
     * @default {Fade}
     */
    transition: PropTypes.oneOfType([
      PropTypes.oneOf([false]),
      PropTypes.elementType,
    ]),
```

According to source code of [`TabPane.js`](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/src/TabPane.js#L95):

```
 const shouldTransition =
    props.transition !== false && rest.transition !== false;

  let key = makeEventKey(props.eventKey);

  return {
    ...props,
    active:
      props.active == null && key != null
        ? makeEventKey(activeKey) === key
        : props.active,
    id: getControlledId(props.eventKey),
    'aria-labelledby': getControllerId(props.eventKey),
    transition:
      shouldTransition && (props.transition || rest.transition || Fade),
    mountOnEnter:
      props.mountOnEnter != null ? props.mountOnEnter : rest.mountOnEnter,
    unmountOnExit:
      props.unmountOnExit != null ? props.unmountOnExit : rest.unmountOnExit,
  };
}
```

If the `props.transition` is not false, `shouldTransition` became true.

So you can do this to prevent the error if transition is a dynamic property:

```
function App() {
  const transition = true;
  return (
   <Tabs transition={transition? null: false>
    <Tab title='Component 1'><Component1/></Tab>
    <Tab title='Component 2'><Component2/></Tab>
</Tabs>
  );
}
```

1. `null` is a valid `PropTypes.elementType`, it prevent the error you got
2. `null !== false`, hence `shouldTransition` became true, it returns the default transition props.

Answer (score 0):

***What I did which worked for me was...***

`import Fade from "react-bootstrap";`

In your code use: `<Tabs transition={Fade}>`

The *transition* prop takes a TransitionType like **Fade** but it also accepts **{false}** but **NOT {true}**

*I hope this helps.*